# Get Total in a single line in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a very simple SQL Query which is getting results in the following way

**COLUMN A           COL-B**

```
WINDCHILL   99.998889 
WINDCHILL   96.000000
```

Now how i can modify my query so that I get the total in a single line? 
**COL-A         COL-B**

```
WINDCHILL   195.99
```

The necessary query is as;

```
 SELECT 
       ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,
       SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours
 FROM
      [IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask] p 
 WHERE
      p.ActualWork > 0 AND 
      ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL) 
 GROUP BY 
      ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]), ActualWork 
 ORDER BY
      p.ActualWork DESC
```

Comment: It's not easy to understand what you're asking here.  Are you just trying to roll up the contents of a column (`GROUP BY`) or pivot a series of values across a row (`PIVOT`) - could you please re-word your question to clarify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You need to modify the GROUP BY and the ORDER BY clauses.*

Try this:

```
SELECT 
       ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,
       SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours
 FROM
      IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask p 
 WHERE
      p.ActualWork > 0 AND 
      ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL) 
 GROUP BY 
      ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) 
 ORDER BY
      SUM(P.ActualWork) DESC
```

As an aside, note that your table is literally named "IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask" and not "TimesheetHoursProjectTask" under the "IR" schema. To specify the later, using the [] notation, it would be [IR].[TimesheetHoursProjectTask].

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to remove the `ActualWork` field in `Group By`.